# Custom canvas.getContext method

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create my own `getContext` method

```
canvas.getContext = (type: string) => {
  return createWebGLContext(canvas)
}
```

I'm trying to assert my custom WebGLRenderingContext to any possible type required by `getContext`

```
const createWebGLContext = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) =>
  new WebGLRenderingContext(canvas) as unknown as
    | (CanvasRenderingContext2D | null)
    | (ImageBitmapRenderingContext | null)
    | (WebGLRenderingContext | null)
    | (WebGL2RenderingContext | null)
    | (RenderingContext | null)
```

and I'm getting an error:

```
Type '(type: string) => WebGLRenderingContext | RenderingContext | null' is not assignable to type '{ (contextId: "2d", options?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings | undefined): CanvasRenderingContext2D | null; (contextId: "bitmaprenderer", options?: ImageBitmapRenderingContextSettings | undefined): ImageBitmapRenderingContext | null; (contextId: "webgl", options?: WebGLContextAttributes | undefined): WebGLRenderin...'.
  Type 'WebGLRenderingContext | RenderingContext | null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | null'.
    Type 'WebGLRenderingContext' is missing the following properties from type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': canvas, getContextAttributes, globalAlpha, globalCompositeOperation, and 59 more.ts(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRB1RAjA4gGQGFw0APWAXhgAphkwA3ZCALhgAkAVAWULsYgCiAG0QBbRGCgBKGOQB8AKBgwwiAO4xMuPACUJAE0TwAlmADmRSYjJUZTGAFcwAazAg1YGEyUwAPtQI%20Jj0wQxNzS1IoACYAET8VByEhKR9-KgBJUWQzRAAhYyhsgAcQsNMLYmtYfzAklLTqLXwyowrI6oS65NTldOa8aNbwyqsyLvrehKph9qrx2smFBUNgIWQkOHBoOCCWdm5eBiZhMQkoAG5lqigAT2LEVmgRmXkYAG8fJCgHeE8EFBoAYdGy0Y4QVIAX2WYP4ADpclAQRRqHcHk8oC9ZHIPl9ED8-nAkKgMNh8MiaHsoUA)

Comment: I get no error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRB1RAjA4gGQGFw0APWAXhgAphkwA3ZCALhgAkAVAWULsYgCiAG0QBbRGCgBKGOQB8AKBgwwiAO4xMuPACUJAE0TwAlmADmRSYjJUZTGAFcwAazAg1YGEyUwAPtQI+Jj0wQxNzS1IoACYAET8VByEhKR9-KgBJUWQzRAAhYyhsgAcQsNMLYmtYfzAklLTqLXwyowrI6oS65NTldOa8aNbwyqsyLvrehKph9qrx2smFBUNgIWQkOHBoOCCWdm5eBiZhMQkoAG5lqigAT2LEVmgRmXkYAG8fJCgHeE8EFBoAYdGy0Y4QVIAXwUQA). Could you provide an example of code with your error ?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRB1RAjA4gGQGFw0APWAXhgAphkwA3ZCALhgAkAVAWULsYgCiAG0QBbRGCgBKGOQB8AKBgwwiAO4xMuPACUJAE0TwAlmADmRSYjJUZTGAFcwAazAg1YGEyUwAPtQI+Jj0wQxNzS1IoACYAET8VByEhKR9-KgBJUWQzRAAhYyhsgAcQsNMLYmtYfzAklLTqLXwyowrI6oS65NTldOa8aNbwyqsyLvrehKph9qrx2smFBUNgIWQkOHBoOCCWdm5eBiZhMQkoAG5lqigAT2LEVmgRmXkYAG8fJCgHeE8EFBoAYdGy0Y4QVIAX2WYP4ADpclAQRRqHcHk8oC9ZHIPl9ED8-nAkKgMNh8MiaHsoUA

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can you also show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of a scenario where you use the overridden method?